# Jquery post recieves data from controller but won't render

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have controller method in my MVC application that I am calling using the jQuery `$.post...`.  The call is executing correctly, processing and sending a valid result back to the view for rendering.  If I alert the result everything is received on the client as expected but the data is not rendered to the view.

The controller method is as below

```
public ActionResult SearchWithCriteria(string search)
{
    var companyList = new Companies().SearchCompanies(search);
    return  PartialView ("Partials\\SearchResults", new SearchViewModel() { SearchResults = companyList });
}
```

and the jQuery is as below

```
$("#submit").bind("click", function () {
                var searchCriteria = $("#SearchCriteria").val();
                if (searchCriteria.length > 0) {
                    $.post('/Search/SearchWithCriteria', { search: searchCriteria }, function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $("companyDetailsSearch").html(data);
                    });
                }
            });
```

The partial is strongly typed and if I put breakpoints on the code I can step through it, but as I say nothing is rendered by the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should...

```
$("companyDetailsSearch").html(data);
```

...really be...

```
$("#companyDetailsSearch").html(data); // use '#' for id's, '.' for classes
```

---

edit: Somehow I managed to write that in the most obfuscated way ever. Basically, 'companyDetailsSearch' isn't a valid selector.  If that's the ID of an element, use the '#' symbol first...

Comment: Thanks for that, it's working now.  Had to be something simple!